# How to get my jquery banner to be random on page refresh, Has timer on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timer, rotator

How to get my jquery banner to be random on page refresh, it has a timer on it so the banner changes every 23 seconds or so without reloading the page.

However the same banner shows up at the start, so i figure it could be fixed with a random page reload jquery.

Here is the code it works fine just need the banners to also refresh when page gets reloaded.

I have tried many options and cant find a solution.

Thanks.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var imgs1 = new Array('https://paidtoclick.ca/bann/ani.gif','https://paidtoclick.ca/bann/247bux.gif','https://paidtoclick.ca/bann/brab.gif ','https://paidtoclick.ca/bann/CHP.gif','https://paidtoclick.ca/bann/Deft.gif','https://paidtoclick.ca/bann/heard.gif','https://paidtoclick.ca/bann/hg1.gif','https://paidtoclick.ca/bann/Hope.gif','https://paidtoclick.ca/bann/lon.jpg','https://paidtoclick.ca/bann/MZJ.gif','https://paidtoclick.ca/bann/oxj.gif','https://paidtoclick.ca/bann/play.jpg','https://paidtoclick.ca/bann/hg2.gif','https://paidtoclick.ca/bann/z8.gif');
var lnks1 = new Array('http://sendearnings.com','http://bucks247.com','http://www.aanbieding.nl','http://coolhandpoker.com','http://www.deftones.com','http://www.ciao.co.uk','https://hostgator.com','https://www.facebook.com/hopenhagen','http://www.thelongevitynowconference.com','http://www.metzonderjas.nl','http://www.oxfam.org.uk/oxjam','https://www.bricksandtoys.nl','https://www.hostgator.com','https://www.zazzle.com/?rf=238005296547767598');
var alt1 = new Array('Featured Weekly Banner','Featured Weekly Banner','Featured Weekly Banner');
var currentAd1 = 0;
var imgCt1 = 14;
function cycle1() {
if (currentAd1 == imgCt1) {
currentAd1 = 0;
}
var banner1 = document.getElementById('adBanner1');
var link1 = document.getElementById('adLink1');
banner1.src=imgs1[currentAd1]
banner1.alt=alt1[currentAd1]
document.getElementById('adLink1').href=lnks1[currentAd1]
currentAd1++;
}
window.setInterval('cycle1()',23000);
</script>
<a href='http://sendearnings.com' id='adLink1' target='_top'>
<img src='https://paidtoclick.ca/bann/ani.gif' id='adBanner1' border='0' width='234' height'60'></a></div>
```

You can view the code in action on the homepage of the site. it works fine just need it reload different banner on page reload https://paidtoclick.ca

Really thanks in advance.

Second banner code...

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var imgs2 = new Array('https://paidtoclick.ca/bann/z1.gif','https://paidtoclick.ca/bann/Survi.gif','https://paidtoclick.ca/bann/hg3.gif','https://paidtoclick.ca/bann/z2.gif','https://paidtoclick.ca/bann/hg4.gif','https://paidtoclick.ca/bann/z3.gif','https://paidtoclick.ca/bann/z4.gif','https://paidtoclick.ca/bann/zoom.gif','https://paidtoclick.ca/bann/z5.gif','https://paidtoclick.ca/bann/hg5.gif','https://paidtoclick.ca/bann/z6.gif','https://paidtoclick.ca/bann/SLS.gif','https://paidtoclick.ca/bann/z7.gif');
var lnks2 = new Array('https://www.zazzle.com/?rf=238005296547767598','http://coolhandpoker.com','https://hostgator.com','https://www.zazzle.com/?rf=238005296547767598','https://hostgator.com','https://www.zazzle.com/?rf=238005296547767598','https://www.zazzle.com/?rf=238005296547767598','http://www.aircraftinteriorsexpo.com','https://www.zazzle.com/?rf=238005296547767598','https://hostgator.com','https://www.zazzle.com/?rf=238005296547767598','http://www.silvalifesystem.com','https://www.zazzle.com/?rf=238005296547767598');
var alt2 = new Array('Featured Weekly Banner','Featured Weekly Banner','Featured Weekly Banner');
var currentAd2 = 0;
var imgCt2 = 13;
function cycle2() {
if (currentAd2 == imgCt2) {
currentAd2 = 0;
}
var banner2 = document.getElementById('adBanner2');
var link2 = document.getElementById('adLink2');
banner2.src=imgs2[currentAd2]
banner2.alt=alt2[currentAd2]
document.getElementById('adLink2').href=lnks2[currentAd2]
currentAd2++;
}
window.setInterval('cycle2()',19000);
</script>
<a href='https://www.zazzle.com/?rf=238005296547767598' id='adLink2' target='_top'>
<img src='https://paidtoclick.ca/bann/z1.gif' id='adBanner2' border='0' width='234' height'60'></a></div>
```

HERE IS THE ENTIRE CODE ON SITE.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

window.onload = function(){
var imgs1 = new Array('https://paidtoclick.ca/bann/ani.gif','https://paidtoclick.ca/bann/247bux.gif','https://paidtoclick.ca/bann/brab.gif ','https://paidtoclick.ca/bann/CHP.gif','https://paidtoclick.ca/bann/Deft.gif','https://paidtoclick.ca/bann/heard.gif','https://paidtoclick.ca/bann/hg1.gif','https://paidtoclick.ca/bann/Hope.gif','https://paidtoclick.ca/bann/lon.jpg','https://paidtoclick.ca/bann/MZJ.gif','https://paidtoclick.ca/bann/oxj.gif','https://paidtoclick.ca/bann/play.jpg','https://paidtoclick.ca/bann/hg2.gif','https://paidtoclick.ca/bann/z8.gif');
var lnks1 = new Array('http://sendearnings.com','http://bucks247.com','http://www.aanbieding.nl','http://coolhandpoker.com','http://www.deftones.com','http://www.ciao.co.uk','https://hostgator.com','https://www.facebook.com/hopenhagen','http://www.thelongevitynowconference.com','http://www.metzonderjas.nl','http://www.oxfam.org.uk/oxjam','https://www.bricksandtoys.nl','https://www.hostgator.com','https://www.zazzle.com/?rf=238005296547767598');
var alt1 = new Array('Featured Weekly Banner','Featured Weekly Banner','Featured Weekly Banner');

var imgCt1 = 14;
var currentAd1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgCt1);
console.log(currentAd1);
function cycle1() {
currentAd1 = (currentAd1 + 1) % imgCt1;
console.log(currentAd1);
var banner1 = document.getElementById('adBanner1');
var link1 = document.getElementById('adLink1');
banner1.src=imgs1[currentAd1]
banner1.alt=alt1[currentAd1]
document.getElementById('adLink1').href=lnks1[currentAd1]
}
cycle1();
window.setInterval(cycle1,23000);
}
</script>
<a href='' id='adLink1' target='_top'>
<img src='' id='adBanner1' border='0' width='234' height'60'></a></div>


<div style='margin-left:-3px; margin-top:-4px;'><script type='text/javascript'>
window.onload = function(){
var imgs2 = new Array('https://paidtoclick.ca/bann/z1.gif','https://paidtoclick.ca/bann/Survi.gif','https://paidtoclick.ca/bann/hg3.gif','https://paidtoclick.ca/bann/z2.gif','https://paidtoclick.ca/bann/hg4.gif','https://paidtoclick.ca/bann/z3.gif','https://paidtoclick.ca/bann/z4.gif','https://paidtoclick.ca/bann/zoom.gif','https://paidtoclick.ca/bann/z5.gif','https://paidtoclick.ca/bann/hg5.gif','https://paidtoclick.ca/bann/z6.gif','https://paidtoclick.ca/bann/SLS.gif','https://paidtoclick.ca/bann/z7.gif');
var lnks2 = new Array('https://www.zazzle.com/?rf=238005296547767598','http://coolhandpoker.com','https://hostgator.com','https://www.zazzle.com/?rf=238005296547767598','https://hostgator.com','https://www.zazzle.com/?rf=238005296547767598','https://www.zazzle.com/?rf=238005296547767598','http://www.aircraftinteriorsexpo.com','https://www.zazzle.com/?rf=238005296547767598','https://hostgator.com','https://www.zazzle.com/?rf=238005296547767598','http://www.silvalifesystem.com','https://www.zazzle.com/?rf=238005296547767598');
var alt2 = new Array('Featured Weekly Banner','Featured Weekly Banner','Featured Weekly Banner');

var imgCt2 = 13;
var currentAd2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgCt2);
console.log(currentAd2);
function cycle2() {
currentAd2 = (currentAd2 + 1) % imgCt2;
console.log(currentAd2);
var banner2 = document.getElementById('adBanner2');
var link2 = document.getElementById('adLink2');
banner2.src=imgs2[currentAd2]
banner2.alt=alt2[currentAd2]
document.getElementById('adLink2').href=lnks2[currentAd2]
}
cycle2();
window.setInterval(cycle2,23000);
}
</script>
<a href='' id='adLink2' target='_top'>
<img src='' id='adBanner2' border='0' width='234' height'60'></a></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should generate a random value for `currentAd1` on the server, or change the js to this:

```
var imgCt1 = 14;
var currentAd1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgCt1);
console.log(currentAd1);
function cycle1() {
    currentAd1 = (currentAd1 + 1) % imgCt1;
    console.log(currentAd1);
    var banner1 = document.getElementById('adBanner1');
    var link1 = document.getElementById('adLink1');
    banner1.src=imgs1[currentAd1]
    banner1.alt=alt1[currentAd1]
    document.getElementById('adLink1').href=lnks1[currentAd1]
}
cycle1();  //you need to execute this once when page loads to change the banner randomly
window.setInterval(cycle1,23000); // no need for 'cycle1()', can just be cycle1
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ggQB6/6/

The best way to do this though is to generate a random `currentAd1` on the server and get rid of the first cycle1() call.

Comment: Hi there, thanks but it does not reload new image on page refresh and also it calls undefined image so no images appear.

Comment: The banners are set with a timer to refresh without page reloading. Really tough piece of code to find a working solution as it has so many images and links that have to correspond. Everything works fine just can not seem to get a new banner to display on page reload for the life of me. lol any help is great thanks.

Comment: hi there just tried the code, and it still does not work always brings up the same banner on reload. How do you set the cycle to 1? Really weird it works fine on the jsfiddle example you gave me but does not work on the site??? I copied the code exactly. from here and not working. Then I tried the code from jsfiddle which works for them and it still did not work?

Comment: And what do you see in the console? There is a console.log(currentAd1); line, which should display a different number each time you load the page. Does it?

Comment: The console log is just displaying currentAd1 no numbers changing on relaod? i left the code on the site check if you like.

Comment: Try wrapping all the js code into a function which should run on window.load. So, first line:  window.onload = function(){ , last line: } . The fiddle code worked because it automatically does this.

Comment: could you please display an example? If not I will try my best to implement it correctly.

Comment: made an updated fiddle, try replacing the code with this one: http://jsfiddle.net/Ngs3j/

Comment: Hi there the code from jsfiddle is up and still not working on page reload. Take a look at site if you like the jsfiddle code is up? Really strange eh?

Comment: Are you sure, seems to be working fine to me. It is the one under the Featured banners section in the middle right of the page?

Comment: Does it have anything to do with the code that displays the jquery... `code` <a href='http://sendearnings.com' id='adLink1' target='_top'>
<img src='https://paidtoclick.ca/bann/ani.gif' id='adBanner1' border='0' width='234' height'60'></a></div> `code`

Comment: It shouldn't. So does it do what it's supposed to do? I'm quite curious about this.

Comment: yes thats the right spot to look. It just keeps showing the "get paid to and more banner" first and when it reloads it keeps showing the same banner. cycle works great just not the page reload.?

Comment: so it does randomize them but it does it after the first one displays. how to change the very first one? is that because its classified in the id of the html and always displays first?

Comment: Yup, you should generate a random currentAd1 on the server if you want it to show a random banner when it first loads, even if the js has not yet run. BTW, it works well on my browser(chrome).

Comment: Okay thanks, on your browser it does not show the green and white banner first at the top all the time? Also any idea how hard it is to generate the currentad1 on the server? Any clues on how to do this properly?

Comment: No problem, glad to help. My browser probably renders the page fast enough, so that the banner changes very quickly, so I don't notice it. To generate it on the server should be pretty easy, just generate a random number in whatever language you are using server-side, and output it in the html, then set the url of the banner straight to that url in the html tag, without going through js. Remember to accept/upvote the answer if it was useful.

Comment: Thanks again but really have no clue how to do this properly. How would i generate a random number? How to output it in html? Never even heard of this way of doing it before. Sorry. ummm. im clueless srry. Any other way to make it work? or any help would be great.

Comment: Well really thanks for your help. I figure out how to fix problem sort of. I removed the initial html image url and it display blank while the browser are loading and when done loading it bring the random banner :) thanks for all your help really thanks a million. will vote it up for sure :)

Comment: That was my idea too, check this fiddle and follow the instructions: http://jsfiddle.net/ggQB6/10/

Comment: Perfect that would have worked just the same :) really thanks again. You got paypal ill send a tip $5. lol if you want just post email.

Comment: :) No need for money, I like to help. An upvote would be nice though!

Comment: Okay will up vote for sure 100%. One more thing I have two banner fields their if i implement the code on both it only displays one. so the top banner works fine how would i make the exact same thing but for the second banner. here is the code for the second banner. its the same as the first but with just values of 2 instead of 1

Comment: Okay I tried and changed the code exactly but now only one banner shows instead of the two of them.

Comment: Well, it looks like the html for the second banner dissapear entirely. Did you delete it, or was it added dinamically?

Comment: Yes the code is in their just for some reason it is displaying the second code now instead of the first and second at once.

Comment: Sorry, you don't have enough rep to chat, try this, and look me up: http://www.chatiw.com/

Comment: Hi i put the entire code on the original question post maybe you can see the problem there? okay on chat username is paidtoclickca